# Laravel keeps using hello@example.com with changed conf

Tags: laravel

In mail.php I have changed from fields but I still get mails with demo values. There is no reference to hello@example.com in project, yet I still get this in mail.

```
'from' => [
        'address' => 'do-not-reply@mysite.net',
        'name' => 'MySite.net',
    ],
```

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: did you try to composer dumpautoload and clear application cache?

Comment: Try php artisan config:clear

Comment: Yeah. That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the config cache by running the following Artisan command:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: @Kira I know, but I came across [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat) recently, so I try to make these community wiki answers for questions that are answered in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **supervisor**, ensure you set the right `user` in the conf file, otherwise you will see the emails are being sent as hello@example.com.

In my case the user is `www-data` - I set it up as root before and was getting this issue.